# Рекурсия на подъеме и спуске

Tags: рекурсия, c++

Доброго времени суток. Есть рекурсивная функция выводящая числа от 10 до 15. Необходимо написать условия чтоб рекурсия выполнялась ка на подъеме так и на спуске

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long int rec(int q, int n)
{   
    if (q <= n)
    {
        cout << q << endl; 
        return rec(q+1, n);
    }
    return q;
}

int main ()
{
    int f = rec(10, 15);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что вы понимаете под выполнением «на подъёме»?

Comment: В одном случаи идут по возрастанию, в другом по убыванию

Answer (score 1):

```
Возможно я не совсем понял но может быть так:

long int rec(int q, int n)
{
    if (q <= n)
    {
        cout << q << endl;
        rec(q+1, n);
        cout << q << endl;
    }
    return q;
}
```